# integrate JAAS with wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaas, wildfly

I have created My LoginModule which integrated with Database.
I try to login and get the principles, and it's working fine;

I need to set the Subject which I get from my LoginModule on the wildfly Subject.

for clarification : when i call [org.jboss.security.SecurityContextAssociation.getSubject()] return same my [ctx.getSubject()];

```
LoginContext ctx = new LoginContext(appName,new MyCallbackHandler(username,password.toCharArray()));

// authenticate user
boolean authenticated = true;
try {
    ctx.login();
} catch (LoginException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    authenticated = false;
}     
  Subject subject = ctx.getSubject();
```

Answer (score 1):

I try the following code, and it's working fine now:)

```
  org.jboss.security.SecurityContextAssociation.getSecurityContext().getSubjectInfo().setAuthenticatedSubject(ctx.getSubject());
```

Thanks